# What is the ideal composition for an organic spacecraft?

Tags: biology, spaceships

One of my interstellar confederations is going to war with another, and has decided to re-purpose the same basic technology they once used to create dyson tree (more like dyson plant-fungus) colonies to grow organic warships cheaply and quickly. The purpose of the ships is to overwhelm- quantity as opposed to quality. Their primary engine is implanted, but most of the craft should be biological.

What is the ideal composition for such craft? Is some sort of organic armor necessary or feasible for them if they're intended to be used basically as canon fodder? Assuming they have the ability to grow any organic substance, what should be the ship's primary material?

Comment: I really want to see some answers to this question!!! Unfortunately, as it's currently written, it might get closed because of how broad/vague it is. Could you clarify the question by providing some details about, eg: 1) What kind of properties you want the ship's hull to have? 2) What kind of power and propulsion they use (real, or "magitech")? How big; are they crewed (ie. does it need life-support)? ... In general, anything that can help people judge what would make one organic material better than another for your purposes.

Comment: As said above, you need to specify what is "ideal" for you: an ideal car for racing in F1 is not the same as an ideal car to transport farmers for potato harvesting.

Comment: Adding to what @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica said, you've asked us to invent an entire space ship. That's too much for a single question. Worse, you've asked for "ideal" answers. Ideal compared to what? (which is L.Dutch's point...). Finally, you've not described your tech at all, which means telling you how that tech is manifest is impossible. Is your organic tech capable of manipulating metals? Then a titanium hull is a good choice, right? This is why we need details: about your tech, your intended use, what limits exist, what resources are available, etc.

Comment: the question may be improved, however, the difficult nature of the stuff makes it harder to formulate - voted for reopening. however if not, then there is no magic - carbon hydrogen oxygen -  those which are on the list of top 5 most abundant elements - as main materials - then it lays well in cannon fodder situation. no armor just shoot it like a missile and rely on numbers.